Appwrite can't get body from request sent by postman
honestly I don't know what I'm missing, but I created a basic function for Appwrite (local hosted).
I have deployed the code manually and if I execute the function via Postman, the context.body is empty.
Body in Postman:

Following is the Result:
{"req":{"bodyRaw":"","body":"","headers":{"host":"localhost","x-appwrite-trigger":"http","x-appwrite-continent-eu":"false","connection":"keep-alive","content-length":"0"},"method":"POST","host":"localhost","scheme":"http","query":{},"queryString":"","port":80,"url":"http://localhost/","path":"/"},"res":{}}

But if i create an execution via the dashboard. The body is accessable.
{"req":{"bodyRaw":"love ya","body":"love ya","headers":{"host":"66b67644edeb5:3000","x-appwrite-trigger":"http","x-appwrite-user-id":"66b5be2000213a91d626","x-appwrite-user-jwt":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2NmI1YmUyMDAwMjEzYTkxZDYyNiIsInNlc3Npb25JZCI6IjY2YjViZTIwYTc3YzY1MTE2MDdkIiwiZXhwIjoxNzIzMjM1MTI3fQ.PIi69nY6kA3sM5xooypaFRsDEds782avlpm9ziVv6Hw","x-appwrite-continent-eu":"false","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","connection":"keep-alive","content-length":"7"},"method":"POST","host":"66b67644edeb5","scheme":"http","query":{},"queryString":"","port":3000,"url":"http://66b67644edeb5:3000/","path":"/"},"res":{}}

Hopefully someone knows, what I'm doing wrong.

Please upload your code as text, not an image.
